# Laravel SB Admin2 component side bar not working

Tags: html, css, templates, components, laravel-8

im new to laravel and in my class project i want to take SB Admin2 template and use it on laravel, since i want to learn how is this made, i took the HTML version and made into sidebar, topbar and content components, rigth now im struggling with the side bar i made it dynamic so i can evaluate the role of the user and render the menus according to it, the sample nav-items work fine but my generated code doesn't, i can't see any diference, can someone give me an advice?

**SIDEBAR GENERATED CODE**

````
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/layout/img/rapidsoft_icon.png">
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">Rapisoft</div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/home">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Home</span></a>
            </li>

<!--GENERATED CODE-->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="/pages" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2collapsePages"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="2collapsePages">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Pages</span>
                </a>
                <div id="2collapsePages" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingPages"
                    data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/our-services">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Our Services</span></a>
            </li>

<!--GENERATED CODE-->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="/about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4collapsePages"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="4collapsePages">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>About</span>
                </a>
                <div id="4collapsePages" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingPages"
                    data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/about-team">About Team</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/about-clients">About Clients</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

<!--GENERATED CODE-->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="/contact" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#9collapsePages"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="9collapsePages">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Contact</span>
                </a>
                <div id="9collapsePages" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingPages"
                    data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/contact-team">Contact Team</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/contact-clients">Contact Clients</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/pqr">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>PQR</span></a>
            </li>

<!--SAMPLE FROM SB ADMIN-->

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsePages"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapsePages">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Paginas</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapsePages" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingPages" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Login Screens:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Login</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="register.html">Register</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password</a>
                        <div class="collapse-divider"></div>
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Other Pages:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="404.html">404 Page</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- PARTE ESTATICA ABAJO -->

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar Message -->
            <div class="sidebar-card d-none d-lg-flex">
                <img class="sidebar-card-illustration mb-2" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/layout/img/undraw_rocket.svg"
                    alt="...">
                <p class="text-center mb-2"> Aca van las notas que se deban tener para cada cliente!!!</p>
            </div>

        </ul>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, this is the code i was using to generate the menu:

```
@if ($menu->parent_id === 0 && $menu->ChCount() === 0)
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/{{$menu->slug}}">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
            <span>{{$menu->menu_title}}</span></a>
    </li>
@else
    @if ($menu->parent_id === 0 and $menu->ChCount() > 0)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="/{{$menu->slug}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$menu->id}}collapsePages"
                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{$menu->id}}collapsePages">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
                <span>{{$menu->menu_title}}</span>
            </a>
            <div id="{{$menu->id}}collapsePages" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingPages" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                    <h6 class="collapse-header"></h6>
                    @foreach($menu->children as $menu)
<a class="collapse-item" href="/{{$menu->slug}}">{{$menu->menu_title}}</a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endif
@endif
```

i found that the ID wasn't captured so it doesnt aplied any css to it, i changed this:
id="{{$menu->id}}collapsePages" for this id="collapse_id{{$menu->id}}" and problem solved.